# iOS / Phonegap: programmatic touch events do not reach the iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

In my Phonegap app (that I test on the iPad Air), I need to fire programmatic events on the elements of an iframe. I've tried:

```
var el = frame.contentDocument.getElementById("existingId");

if (el)
{
  var touches = frame.contentDocument.createTouchList();
  var event = frame.contentDocument.createEvent('TouchEvent');

  if (event.initUIEvent)
  {
    event.initUIEvent(
      'touchstart',                // {String}    type
      true,                 // {Boolean}   canBubble
      true,                 // {Boolean}   cancelable
      frame.contentWindow, // {Window}    view
      1,                    // {Number}    detail
      0,                    // {Number}    screenX
      0,                    // {Number}    screenY
      0,                    // {Number}    clientX
      0,                    // {Number}    clientY
      false,                // {Boolean}   ctrlKey
      false,                // {Boolean}   altKey
      false,                // {Boolean}   shiftKey
      false,                // {Boolean}   metaKey
      touches,              // {TouchList} touches
      touches,              // {TouchList} targetTouches
      touches,              // {TouchList} changedTouches
      0,                    // {Number}    scale(0 - 1)
      0                     // {Number}    rotation
    );

    event.target = el;

    el.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

But this code leads to nothing; event gets dispatched, but element in the frame with id = 'existingId' doesn't receive the touchstart event.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? I solved it using getParent, but I can't remember exactly the order

Comment: @Del - I'm not sure if it's an iOS or Phonegap-related, but will try to compose a sample shortly.

Comment: Its just javascript problem, iframes are not easy to handle